# Why is my Javascript not adding data on submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a hot and Cold App in JS and jQuery.

My issue is on form submit that user input inserts a number and the game tells them if its hold or cold or hotter or holder based on how close or far from the number.

Issue is that It only works the first time. After that it does nothing.

How do I made it so that when the user input on submit it generates a new secretNumber and based on the checker I have setup outputs either hot or cold or hotter or colder.

Seems its not generating a new secret number or it is just not inputing it.

Code here http://codepen.io/mackenzieabby/pen/qOXNLg

JS

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    // Global Variables.
    var theSecret = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 0); // Creates Secret Number
    var userGuess = $('#userGuess').val(); // User Inut Guess
    var count = 0;
    var addList = document.createElement("li")
    // Display information modal box
  $(".what").click(function(){
  $(".overlay").fadeIn(1000);
    });

    // Hide information modal box 
    $("a.close").click(function(){
    $(".overlay").fadeOut(1000);
    });

   // Functions

   // New Game
   function newGame() {
    // new gama data here
   }

   // Add To List
   function addtoList() {
   }

   function preventRefresh() {
    $("form").submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      theSecret();
      veryHotGuess();
      hotGuess();
      veryColdGuess();
      coldGuess()
      correctAnswer();
    });
   }
   preventRefresh();

   function addGuess() {
   $("ul#guessList").append("<li>" + userGuess + "</li>");
   }


   // Checks if hot or cold or correct

function veryHotGuess() {
  if (userGuess < 25 && theSecret < 25) {
    document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Very Hot";
   }
}

function hotGuess() {
  if (userGuess < 50 && theSecret < 50) {
    document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Hot";
  }
}

function veryColdGuess() {
  if (userGuess < 100 && theSecret < 100) {
    document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Very Cold";
   }
}

function coldGuess() {
  if (userGuess < 75 && theSecret < 75) {
    document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Cold";
   }
}

function correctAnswer() {
  if (userGuess == theSecret) {
    document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "You Got It";
  }
}  

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't with `theSecret` but with `userGuess`. You were not grabbing the value on submit so it was empty. I suggest to always console.log or inspect variables to make sure they are getting populated correctly. In your submit I added this: `userGuess = $('#userGuess').val();` and it will now check correctly.

However, as Alexander mentioned the math is wrong. The value will always be under 100 and so it will always be Very Cold. You have to get the absolute difference of both numbers and then do your guess check:

```
  var difference = Math.abs(theSecret - userGuess);

  if (difference < 100) {
    document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Very Cold";
  }
  if (difference < 75) {
    document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Cold";
  }
  if (difference < 50) {
    document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Hot";
  }
  if (difference < 25) {
    document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Very Hot";
  }      
  if (difference == 0) {
    document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "You Got It";
  }
```

I forked your project here: http://codepen.io/paulmg/pen/xwLExM

Comment: Thanks. Been woking in this all day.
Appriciate it and now I udnerstand the issue

Comment: Glad it helped. You are on the right path. Please set this to accepted if it answered the question. Thanks

Comment: Have done so. This is my first week of 10 hour a day learning.
Hope to be work ready in 3 months.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `theSecret();` causes a JavaScript error. You are calling the variable as a function, which it isn’t obviously.

BTW, I think your calculation of guess "temperature" might be quite wrong.

Comment: Code was updated. As you can see once you input the first number it runs the code but when you do it again nothing happens. Any reason as to how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to redefine your definition of Global variable in javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Global Variables.
    var theSecret = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 0); // Creates Secret Number
    var userGuess = $('#userGuess').val(); // User Inut Guess
    var count = 0;
    var addList = document.createElement("li")

    ...
```

those **ARE NOT** global variables, because you made then in a scope, the `document.ready` scope... a Global Variable must be defined outside any scope, so it's available in all scopes, including inside the `document.ready` as well inside any `function` method you wrote.

**Secondly**, you need to rethink what you are doing, as a rule, you are repeating yourself over and over with

```
document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = xxxx;
```

one day you need to change the `feedback` to something else, or also write something else, can you see in how many places you need to change your code? When you see several lines of almost the same code: You're doing it wrong...

And you need to simplify your calculations, you make it hard to code and see what's going on...

**Third**, as [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4149783/alexander-bondar) pointed out, you need to re-think how you're calculating, what you want to calculate if not the `userGuess` or the `theSecret`, but give an answer based on how close/far the user guess is from the correct value ... that I would call it the difference between 2 numbers.

something like: `Math.abs(theSecret - userGuess)`

Here's my approach:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKqzvg?editors=001

---

*(irrelevant code removed)*

```
var theSecret = 0,
    guesses = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Creates Secret Number
  theSecret = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 0);

  $("form").submit(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    checkTemperature();
  });
});

// Functions

// Add To List
function addToList(txt) {
  guesses.push(txt);
  $("#count").text(guesses.length);
  $("ul#guessList").append("<li>" + txt + "</li>");
}

function write(txt) {
  document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = txt;
}

function checkTemperature() {
  var userGuess = parseInt($('#userGuess').val()),
    dif = Math.abs(theSecret - userGuess);

  // for debug only
  console.log("theSecret:" + theSecret);
  console.log("userGuess:" + userGuess);
  console.log("dif:" + dif);

  addToList(userGuess);

  if (dif < 5)
    write("Vulcan Hot");
  else if (dif < 25)
    write("Very Hot");
  else if (dif < 50)
    write("Hot");
  else if (dif < 75)
    write("Cold");
  else if (dif < 100)
    write("Very Cold");
  else if (dif === 0)
    write("You Got It");
}
```

Comment: Appriciate it. I am new to this js and jQuery. I will remember that.

Comment: I thought so, hence the log explanation... But no matter what the technology, even a pencil and a paper, you do need to understand that if you have a **(a)** number and a second **(b)** number, and now you want to see if the guess is close or far from the original number, you would be better using a third number that is the difference between the 2... no?

Comment: I go so caught up I left the numbers behind.